# Google search console error: Sitemap couldn't fetch

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

My webpage is heavily reliant on organic traffic, but my SEO updates haven't been captured since November 12th due to an error saying "Sitemap couldn't fetch" in GSC. This is critical to my business.

My sitemap looks fine in the browser, but when I run URL inspection on my domain in GSC I get the following: "coverage = indexed, not submitted in sitemaps" and "sitemaps = N/A".

[image]

When I request indexing it says "Indexing request rejected" and "During live testing, indexing issues were detected with the URL". Live testing also fails saying "URL is not on google" even though it is..

Comment: Crazy question, did you submit your website to Google Search Console with the **https** url and not trying to work on the **http** which for Google is another website?

Comment: Gael, I am only analysing https URLs which is what my sitemaps contains exclusively. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I guess so. It was just to verify you were not analysing the wrong Property (without https). Sorry but the only clue I found here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/124264/100276 is to wait for Google to fix new search console bug and not resubmit your sitemap until that :/

Comment: Sitemaps have little bearing on what pages Google chooses to index or on your rankings.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)  If you site is set up properly, Googlebot will be able to crawl it and find new content.   Not sure what the issue is with your sitemap, but it has nothing to do with Google not seeing your "SEO updates".  What exactly is an "SEO update" anyway?